# Can't Find simplepie.inc in Version 1.3.1

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I am trying Simple Pie for the first time and I'm running into a problem. I downloaded the new 1.3.1 version and unzipped it. I set up everything according to the instructions (created the php and cache folders in my root directory, loaded the library and php auto-loader.php file into the php folder, and set the permissions to 755 on the cache folder). However, despite looking at every single file in the Simple-pie folder I can't find the simplepie.inc file. I have searched Google for someplace to find it but I can't find anything and I've searched on here for solutions but I don't see anything. Can someone please tell me where to get the simple-pie.inc file?

If version 1.3.1 doesn't include it how can people that download that version use the program?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It does. It exists in the library folder.

However you should not include the autoloader.php (if you are using the stock download and not your own build)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the documentation for SimplePie perhaps needs updating, a lot of the examples use the older versions and may not work with the most recent version, I know I had to do significant heavy lifting to get the News Blocks 2.0 demo to work. And it still doesn't do everything POPURLS does, SimplePie is a beginning not necessarily an end, but it does work, assuming you give it good feeds. Poorly formatted feeds ie feeds that do not conform to RSS or Atom standards can bring your playhouse crashing down.

I just have this in [my news aggregator](http://news.muschamp.ca) index.php:

```
require_once('../news/php/autoloader.php');
```

Eventually they updated their documentation and the default download.